# Make build artifacts avalible for "gitlab free" users

Tags: gitlab

When doing a gitlab release, we a certain artifacts (translations, other files) to the release page. This files are accessible for all developers, which have a paid gitlab subscription. However not all users in our companies have a paid account, since it is not necessary for e.g. the translation department.

How can we make the artifacts still available for those "gitlab free" users?

[image: example]